# Extrair o preço de um texto e mostrá-lo formatado

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Preciso resolver esta questão:

> Considerando o trecho de um texto extraído de uma página de pesquisa
> de vôos:
>
> -Melhor preço sem escalas R$ 1.367
> -Melhor preço com escalas R$ 994
>
> 1 - Incluindo todas as taxas.
>
> Escreva uma expressão regular para localizar o melhor preço com ou sem
> escalas, depois utilize sua expressão para extrair a string
> correspondente ao valor escolhido e em seguida converta o resultado em
> valor decimal (float) de forma que tenhamos apenas "1367.00" ou
> "994.00" .

Eu cheguei a fazer a seguinte expressão:

```
$preco = "R$ 1.367";
$validaPreco = preg_match('/^[0-9]$/', $preco);
```

Só que eu não sei como fazer para remover o `R$` e conseguir resolver a questão.

Como vocês fariam isso?

Answer (score 2):

Se o texto **sempre** tem esse formato, então bastaria pegar os trechos "R$ etc":

```
function formatar($preco) {
    return number_format(str_replace('.', '', $preco), 2, '.', '');
}

$texto = 'Melhor preço sem escalas R$ 1.367\n-Melhor preço com escalas R$ 994';
if (preg_match('/sem escalas R\$ (\d+(?:\.\d{3})*).*com escalas R\$ (\d+(?:\.\d{3})*)/s', $texto, $matches)) {
    echo "Sem escalas: ". formatar($matches[1]);
    echo "\nCom escalas: ". formatar($matches[2]);
}
```

`\d+` pega um ou mais dígitos, e em seguida há um trecho `\.\d{3}` (um ponto seguido de 3 dígitos), só que todo este trecho está agrupado entre parênteses e com o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências). Ou seja, eu posso ter "ponto seguido de 3 dígitos" sendo repetido zero ou mais vezes (talvez seja exagero porque o preço de uma passagem não vai ser mais de 1 milhão de reais, então poderia ser também `(\d+(?:\.\d{3})?)` - o `?` indica que o trecho é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)).

Todo o trecho que me interessa (o valor numérico) está entre parênteses, pois assim forma um [grupo de captura](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) que eu posso recuperar depois. O primeiro preço (sem escalas) estará no primeiro grupo (`$matches[1]`) e o segundo preço estará em `$matches[2]`. Já o trecho "ponto seguido de 3 dígitos" está com `(?:` - isso forma um grupo de não-captura, assim eu não crio grupos à toa no array `$matches` - só me interessa os preços completos.

Eu também uso `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres) e a [*flag* `s`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) faz com que o ponto também corresponda a quebras de linha (já que os textos parecem estar em linhas diferentes).

Tendo os preços, posso formatá-los da maneira que achar melhor. Ao formatar, eliminei o ponto porque ao converter a string para número o ponto é usado como separador decimal (então `1.367` seria interpretado como 1,367 e não como "mil trezentos e sessenta e sete"). Depois eu formato este número para ter apenas duas casas decimais, usando o ponto como separador decimal e sem separador entre os milhares (veja a [documentação de `number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) para mais detalhes).

A saída do código é:

```
Sem escalas: 1367.00
Com escalas: 994.00
```

---

A sua regex `^[0-9]$` não funciona porque ela usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` (respectivamente o início e fim da string) e só vê se tem um único dígito (ou seja, a string só poderia ter um caractere, que é um dígito de 0 a 9).

Comment: Testado e aprovado! https://ideone.com/iHvAKx

Answer (score -1):

```
(?<=R\$ )\d+.?\d+
```

Dessa forma o `R$` fica dentro de um grupo de checagem que não fará parte do match